# How do I get a .name domain name

Tags: domains, domain-registration

There was a service which provided email aliases on .name domain, but it seem to be gone now, so I was thinking of actually getting a domain for myself (*martin.toth.name* sounds nice).

Do I understand it correctly, that I can't get a toth.name domain, but only third level: martin.toth.name? Do I get to have @toth.name emails even then?

I've tried several registrars from [Verisign's list](http://www.verisign.com/domain-name-services/find-registrar/index.html), but none of them let's me ask for the third level, nor the toth.name (some say it's taken, some that it can't be registered).

There's an article linked from Wikipedia entry on .name about cybercrime on .name. Should I look for another top level domain? Is it a disadvantage in search engines or anywehere else? *Note: couldn't post links to those pages, because I'm low on reputation*

So basically: **How does one register a .name domain name?**

Comment: I was able to apply to register martin.toth.name (I didn't buy it; I just checked it and was told it was available and automatically added to my cart) via one of the registrars, but that registrar has some serious issues (invalid SSL certificate). Unfortunately with the state of domain registrars today, you've gotta dig through a lot of crud to get to a trustworthy AND competent company. And .name is a particularly difficult TLD to register with because of its unconventional assignment structure. Keep trying and avoid the companies with names like "!$#$ Sleazy Co.".

Comment: Frankly, I'd just ditch `.name` and go with `martintoth.com`. It's available, shorter, more recognizable, and you can easily register it with a reputable registrar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my [rob.olmos.name](http://rob.olmos.name) from DynDNS for $15. Unfortunately, *olmos.name* is only third-level registrable due to it being deemed a common last name.

However, [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) offers the ability to setup email forwarding for a username on the second-level domain on a first-come-first-serve basis and I picked up *rob[@]olmos[.]name* (which I think is sweet) for another $10.

That being said, good luck with getting far with a .name domain as you can see the trouble there already is with just the registrars searching and registering them. Rackspace Cloud Sites doesn't properly handle third-level .name so I just went with my own cloud server. I didn't try other hosting providers so I can't comment.

Best to ask first if the email forwarding is available (if you have to do a third-level) for the first name with the registrar you go with **before** registering the domain to find it's already taken or not.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a website which I forgot, but the important thing is that http://dd24.net/ bought them (and they are ICANN certified).

Comment: Are you thinking of "Free Your ID"? That's the company I used to buy `timothy.green.name`.

Answer (score 0):

When you register a domain, you can only register one level up from the domain extension, so you would need to register  `toth.name`, and then create a subdomain of `martin` in your DNS for `toth.name`. (note: This is different to what used to be the rules, they where changed to make `.name` work the same as `.com`)

Looking at that verisign list, most of those registrars looke very, very dodgey. 1and1 are not dodgey however, [but their domain check](http://order.1and1.com/xml/order/Home) seems to be broken at the moment. If toth.name really is taken, then you can always register `xn--tth-gna.name` (which is punycode for `tóth.name`)

Comment: Toth.name is not registered by anyone else, it has been deemed a "shared name" by VeriSign.

Comment: `.name` is weird. I bought `timothy.green.name`, which means that `green.name` itself is unavailable for registration. However, as part of the package I also got `timothy@green.name` as a forwarding e-mail address.